# Loop through and Merge arrays of object to get a new object

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of objects I want to merge, array of object with the same Class and create a new object based on the value
Let's have a look at an example.

````
    [{
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_on_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "BOTTOM",
                "FLAG": 1,
                "DATE": "2022-09-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-29T06:30:00.000Z"
            },
             {
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_off_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "BOTTOM",
                "FLAG": 2,
                "DATE": "2022-09-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-29T21:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_on_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "TOP",
                "FLAG": 1,
                "DATE": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-30T07:30:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_off_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "TOP",
                "FLAG": 2,
                "DATE": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-30T21:30:00.000Z"
            }] ```
````

> I am looping through an array of objects and comparing CLASS. I am doing it this way but no good. Been stuck with this and would really appreciate any help

````
    array.reduce((acc, value) => {
        const fIndex = acc.findIndex(v => v.CLASS === value.CLASS);
        if (fIndex >= 0) {
          acc[fIndex] = { ...acc[fIndex],
            ...value
          }
        } else {
          acc.push(value);
        }
        return acc;
      }, []); ```
````

Expected output would be:

````
    {
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_off_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "TOP",
                "FLAG": 2,
                "DATE": "2022-09-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-29T21:30:00.000Z",
                "newTIME": "2022-09-29T07:30:00.000Z"
            },
    {
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_off_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "BOTTOM",
                "FLAG": 2,
                "DATE": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-30T21:30:00.000Z",
                "newTIME": "2022-09-30T06:30:00.000Z"
            }. ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what kind of merge do you want...
When you have

```
{
            "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
            "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_on_period",
            "SYSTEM": "TANE",
            "CLASS": "BOTTOM",
            "FLAG": 1,
            "DATE": "2022-09-29T00:00:00.000Z",
            "TIME": "2022-09-29T06:30:00.000Z"
        },
         {
            "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
            "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_off_period",
            "SYSTEM": "TANE",
            "CLASS": "BOTTOM",
            "FLAG": 2,
            "DATE": "2022-09-29T00:00:00.000Z",
            "TIME": "2022-09-29T21:30:00.000Z"
        }
```

What is the merge between them ?

Comment: There are two different TIME. I wanna create a new object with  the different TIME together in the new object. eg  {
                "UNIQUE_ID": 1083,
                "METRIC_NAME": "tuesday_1_off_period",
                "SYSTEM": "TANE",
                "CLASS": "BOTTOM",
                "FLAG": 2,
                "DATE": "2022-09-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "TIME": "2022-09-30T21:30:00.000Z",
                "newTIME": "2022-09-30T06:30:00.000Z"
            }